# images dont render on first page

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

i am trying to make a simple app that calls an api and the renders 10 images per page.
the first page loads but does not show images but the second page does.

what am i doing wrong?

```
let imageData = [];

fetch({api}
).then(res => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    imageData.push(...data.results)
  })
fetch({api}
).then(res => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    imageData.push(...data.results)
  })

let currentPage = 1;
let imagesPerPage = 10;

const changePage = (page)=> {

  let nextBttn = document.getElementById("nextBttn");
  let prevBttn = document.getElementById("prevBttn");
  let root = document.getElementById("root");
  let pageCount = document.getElementById("page");

  if (page < 1) page = 1;
  if (page > numPages()) page = numPages();

  root.innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = (page - 1) * imagesPerPage; i < (page * imagesPerPage) && i < imageData.length; i++) {
    const createImage = document.createElement('img')
    createImage.src = imageData[i].urls.thumb
    createImage.setAttribute('id',imageData[i].id)
     root.appendChild(createImage)
  }
  
  pageCount.innerHTML = page + "/" + numPages();

window.onload = ()=>{
     changePage(1);
};
```

there are two fetches because it returns 30 images and i need 60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have two (three technically) asynchronous tasks running
that depend on one another, but without any code to synchronize them back up.

Here's the possible order of events:

1. You initiate a fetch of the first 30 images
2. You initiate a fetch of the second 30 images
3. No matter how fast these requests are, their callback won't fire until the rest of this code is parsed/executed.
4. You set a callback for Page Load

Here's where things can get wonky.

Scenario A (unlikely, you wouldn't have an error):
The server is fast as heck (or cached response) and already has a response waiting for you. In theory, I believe its possible the fetch callback fires before the page load (though I could be wrong here). In this unlikely scenario, the response data is loaded into the imageData. Then the page load event fires, and calls changePage, which displays the images from imageData.

Scenario B (most likely):
The server takes some milliseconds to respond but the page elements are all created and therefore onLoad callback fires first. It attempts to display the imageData (but there isn't any yet). The server finally responds with the 60 images. No code is executed that tells the webpage to draw this new image data.

As you can see, because your code assumes the image data is already available when it tries to display some images on page load (not data load), it fails when the image data takes awhile to return and upon returning does not notify the page to display the new image data.

Here's how you can modify it:

```
let response1 = fetch({api})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    imageData.push(...data.results)
  });
let response2 = fetch({api})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    imageData.push(...data.results)
  });

Promise.all([response1, response2])
  .then(() => changePage(1));

// Remove onLoad callback because we don't really care when the page loads, we care when the data loads.
```